# Reprojecting multiple rasters in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.0

I have classified layers of Landsat 5 and 7 of several years in Geographic coordinate system WGS84.

To reproject this to UTM, is there a simpler way than using Project Raster tool in ArcToolbox?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to re-project many rasters in a directory in batch you could create a model using the [Iterate Files](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00400000000v000000.htm) and funnel those found rasters into the project tool.